# Host different UITableViewControllers in one UIViewController like a Calendar App with multiple views

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have an app that has two separate views of a schedule, one is a list view of the events, the other is a UICollectionView which presents as a calendar in month view. I want to create a new view that has a UISegmentControl in the TitleView that allows the user to switch between List and Month views. Instead of using a menu to navigate to two different views, they will be selectable and hosted in a single view. How do I architect this in iOS 10 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Take UIViewControlle, add UISegmentControl and UICollectionView.
create two customised UIcollectionviewcell inside UICollectionView, One for Listview and one for Month view as in following image.

[image: Components on UIViewcontroller]

Now, According to selection of Segment control, change Data in collection view by using required cell from getcell function. use collectionview.reaload() function reload data on segment selection change event.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but you may have misread my use of the collection view. Let me clarify...take a scenario of having two UITableViewControllers that are two separate areas of the app. I want to create a single View that allows the user to toggle between these two UITableViewControllers.